# C - fgets() - length of newline char

Tags: c, char, newline, fgets

I am trying to read 1 line and I am not sure how newline char is represented. Should I consider it as 2 chars or 1 char, when reading it from file by fgets() ? For example, I have a line of 15 chars + new line in file. So how should I safely allocate string and read that line?

At first, I tried this:

```
char buf[16];
fgets(buf, 16, f);
```

It read the line correctly without newline char and I assume that buf[15] holds the null character.

However, when I want to read and store the newline char, it doesn't work as I thought. As far as I know, '\n' should be considered as one char and take just one byte, so to read it, I just need to read one more char.

But when i try this

```
char buf[17];
fgets(buf, 17, f);
```

it does completely the same thing than previous example - there is now newline char stored in my string (I am not sure where null char is stored in this case)

To read entire line with newline I need to do this

```
char buf[18];
fgets(buf, 18, f);
```

OR this (it works, but I am not sure if it's safe)

```
char buf[17];
fgets(buf, 18, f);
```

So the questions is, why do I need to allocate and read 18 chars, when the line has only 15 chars + newline?

Comment: "it works, but I am not sure if it's safe" <- it isn't safe. If the line is long enough, `fgets` writes outside the buffer.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: Can you check the line contents (with the 18 byte buffer and `fgets`) whether there's a '\r' at position 15?

Comment: In Windows, newline is two characters: `"\r\n"`.

Comment: on buf[15] there is something with ASCI code 13 (which is probably '\r'), buf[16] holds '\n' and buf[17] is null char. Ok, thanks for help, now I see why I need 2 chars for newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide buffer space for the 15-chars of text, up to 2 characters for the new line (to handle Windows line termination of `\r\n`), and one more for the null termination.  So that's 18.

Like you did here:

```
char buf[18]; fgets(buf, 18, f);
```

The `num` parameter to `fgets` tells the call the size of your buffer it's writing to.

Comment: Well I knew that, I just didn't know WHY do I need to allocate 2 chars for newline. Now I see that newline is actually 2 chars -> '\r' + '\n'. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user10099 Ah, ok.  Added a note as to why.

Comment: No, you normally *don't* need to allocate 2 characters for the newline. Open the file in text mode, and the library will convert whatever the OS uses to a single `'\n'` character. (Unless you're reading a file created on a different OS and not properly converted.)

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to read 1 line and I am not sure how newline char is represented.

In text mode, newline is '\n' and that's true on any conform C implementation and I wouldn't use fgets on anything but a text mode stream (I don't know -- and I don't want to know -- how it works in binary mode on an implementation using \r as end of line marker, or worse using an out of band end of line marker, I wouldn't be surprised it looks for a \n and never find one thus try to read until the end of file).

You should allocate space for the maximal line length, included the newline plus the terminating NUL and more important you must never lie the fgets about the length of the buffer. You can check if the buffer was long enough as the newline won't be present if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am not really sure what do you mean by text mode and binary mode. For now I will just allocate 2 chars for newline + 1 char for nullchar + x chars for max line length and it should not cause any trouble when I use it on same machine

Comment: @user10099 File can be opened in binary mode or in text mode, please read fopen docs. In most Unixes/Linux these are same, but in Mac and Win not same at all, so it is important to use right mode. In text mode, C string always has just \n as new line, no matter what it is in actual file on disk.

Comment: I read some docs, and it says that every file is opened in text mode by default and filtering of new line chars depends on compiler. So i guess I'll just have to handle both '\n' and '\r\n' to make it safe.

Comment: @user0099, if you open it in text mode, you shouldn't see \r\n for valid text files. (There is the possibility of importing a file with \r\n in an OS which just use \n without doing the conversion and where the runtime will not filter out \r).

Comment: I tried to open file by fopen(FILE_PATH, "rt"); instead of fopen(FILE_PATH, "r"); and yes, there are no \r\n, just \n .. so that pretty much solves everything I hope .. thought that text files are opened in text mode by default. Thank you

Comment: @user10099, "r" is the standard way to ask for a text file, and "rt" isn't defined by the standard (but it is a compliant extension to give a signification to it).

Comment: @hyde: Modern MacOS uses Unix-style LF to terminate lines.

Answer (score 0):

The matter is about the espace sequence that lets you test for a newline, it is two characters \0x0d\0x0a but when using a strcmp and need to provide a string for this and a length, the C escape code holds in one character, so you must:

```
if(strncmp(&buff[i], "\n", 1) == 0)
```

which would not work with a length of two. Don't ask me why.